# Can't install a specific kustomize version

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am trying to install kustomize v3.2.1 in Mac, but I am getting the following error when I do these steps.

wget "https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/archive/refs/tags/kustomize/v3.2.1.tar.gz" Untar the source

tar xzf xxxxx.tar.gz cd xxxxxx make install

Output:

```
go install /cmd/kustomize
make: go: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
How can I install this version without any issues? Thanks!
```

I need to recreate this question as I wasnt able to answer my previous question. So the command below is not working with specific version of kustomize

```
# install a particular version
brew install kustomize@v3.2.1
```

In brew, there is only the latest version available

Comment: [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: Have you tried installing via instructions in the below link?
https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/installation/kustomize/source/#install-the-kustomize-cli-from-local-source-with-cloning-the-repo

Comment: @Luuk homebrew has the latest version in kustomize.

Comment: @rock'nrolla thanks for sharing it. I tried the commands, but when I run (cd kustomize; go install .) command I get.    go: sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/v3@v3.3.1: missing go.sum entry; to add it: go mod download sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/v3, after that just getting this one go mod download: skipping argument sigs.k8s.io/kustomize/v3 / I couldn't figure it out

Comment: On the [release](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/tag/kustomize%2Fv3.2.1) there is a build version for [kustomize@3.2.1](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/download/kustomize%2Fv3.2.1/kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64)

Comment: @Luuk, yeah but the thing, I couldn't install that. When I run brew install kustomize@3.2.1command, I get this No available formula or cask with the name "kustomize@3.2.1". So I really feel bad that I can't install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the version from [release](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/releases/tag/kustomize%2Fv3.2.1) into my `temp` folder. No need to install anything

Optionally you can rename `kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64` to `kustomize`.

```
luuk@mini temp % ./kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64 version
Version: {Version:kustomize/v3.2.1 GitCommit:d89b448c745937f0cf1936162f26a5aac688f840 BuildDate:2019-09-27T00:10:52Z GoOs:darwin GoArch:amd64}
luuk@mini temp % ./kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64 help

Manages declarative configuration of Kubernetes.
See https://sigs.k8s.io/kustomize

Usage:
  kustomize [command]

Available Commands:
  build       Print configuration per contents of kustomization.yaml
  config      Config Kustomize transformers
  create      Create a new kustomization in the current directory
  edit        Edits a kustomization file
  help        Help about any command
  version     Prints the kustomize version

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for kustomize

Use "kustomize [command] --help" for more information about a command.
luuk@mini temp %
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment here. I use mac and tried to do so but it didnt work. I guess that one is for linux. ./kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64: command not found.

Comment: `darwin_amd64` in the filename suggest that it is for a Mac, running on 64-bits Intel processor

Comment: I see, I followed the way you said. Just saying command not found.

Comment: you should make it executable, using: `chmod +x kustomize_kustomize.v3.2.1_darwin_amd64`

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked now! Any idea on how I can run `kustomize` command instead of using `./`

Comment: Please read: [What is PATH on a Mac OS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111550/what-is-path-on-a-mac-os)   It is explained there that you can copy this executable to 'a' directory which is in the PATH.